# How to retrieve deleted files from Visual Studio 2013 after removing mapped to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have an MVC application and I created new file(.cshtml) in the View folder, the changes was stored in my local machine but when I tried to remove mapping from the source control I can't find the physical file. Is there any other option where I can find the missing/deleted files? It's seems odd, because my changes in the existing controllers and scripts are still there only the added file was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for your loss. TFS didn't delete anything. If you checked all in before you removed the mapping. The source is almost in the repos.You would see that there was a changeset with "Delete" operations against your file. Then should be able to roll back that changeset and get all of your file. But if not **it is already gone**.

For more detailed explanation, please refer the similar question:  [TFS deleted my files when changing the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266755/tfs-deleted-my-files-when-changing-the-mapping)

Comment: My bad.. I recreated all of my scripts. Btw, thanks for the info.